# is there a function in python to round off three digits after decimal but show all three digits even if zero

Tags: python

i want to round off number 7.00087 and output should be 7.000

I tried round() function but it eliminates zero.

Comment: Should it not be `7.001` ? if you are rounding ?

Answer (score 0):

This function gives the right output:

```
def my_round(x, decimals):
    str_decimals = str(x % int(x))
    return str(int(x)) + str_decimals[1 : 2 + decimals]
```

What does `my_round()` do:

1- It retrieves decimals in a `string` format as a variable named `str_decimals`

2- Concatenates rounded `int(x)` with desired decimals and return as output.

Let's apply it:

**Input**

```
x = 7.00087
y = my_round(x, 3)
print(y)
```

**Ouput**

```
>>> 7.000
```